# Does the random graph interpret the random directed graph?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, random-graphs, directed-graphs

The random graph is the Fraisse limit of the class of finite graphs, the random directed graph is the Fraisse limit of the class of directed graphs, a directed graph is just a set with a binary relation.

It's easy to see that the random directed graph interprets the random graph, in fact the second is a reduct of the first. I am curious to know about the other direction. I don't see an easy way to do it, or an easy way to rule it out. More generally, I would be curious have pointers to research on when countable homogeneous structures interpret other countable homogeneous structures. I don't know if anyone has thought about this, I'm not very familiar with that terrain.

Motivation: I am doing some work with a weak notion of interpretability. I show that the random graph weakly interprets the random directed graph, and I use this as a fairly important lemma. So I'm curious to know if anything is known/obvious to experts about actual interpretations. If there is an actual interpretation then it would be a bit silly to spend a page constructing a weak interpretation.

I am actually thinking about the random $k$-ary hypergraph and the random $k$-ary relation.

Comment: On "pointers to research on when countable homogeneous structures interpret other countable homogeneous structure": It's a theorem of Ahlbrandt and Ziegler that an $\aleph_0$-categorical structure $A$ interprets a structure $B$ if and only if there is a continuous homomorphism $f\colon \mathrm{Aut}(A)\to \mathrm{Aut}(B)$ such that the action of $\mathrm{im}(f)$ on $B$ has only finitely many orbits.

Comment: Of course, it's not clear in practice that showing that such a homomorphism does not exist is any easier than showing there is no interpretation directly... In the case when $B$ is the random $k$-ary relation, $B$ has the lovely property that for any finite partition of $B$, one of the pieces is isomorphic to $B$. So by restricting to one of the orbits, we may assume that the action of $\mathrm{im}(f)$ on $B$ is transitive.

Comment: thanks for reminding me of that. I thought about this a little - we can also remove the assumption that $f$ is continuous. Kechris and Rosendal show that the automorphism group of the random graph has a comeager conjugacy classes, so any homomorphism to a separable group is continuous.

Comment: Is it enough to interpret vertices as vertices, and interpret a directed edge from $P$ to $S$ as a set of five edges $\{PQ, QR, RS, QR’, R’S\}$? (The pattern looks like -<>.)

Comment: @MattF. I don’t understand your construction. In the random graph, for every $P$ and $S$ there exist $Q,R,R'$ that have your edge pattern, hence the directed graph you interpreted is just the complete graph. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It should follow easily from quantifier elimination that there is no *1-dimensional* interpretation of the random directed graph in the random graph.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I think that the one-dimensional case also follows from Simon Thomas's classification of reducts of the random graph (there are only like 5 reducts)

Comment: I guess I can see one approach: let $(V,E)$ be the random graph. For each $n$ put some reasonable structure $\mathcal{V}_n$ on $V^n$, so that $\mathcal{V}_n$ is also a Friasse limit, and $\mathcal{V}_n$ is interdefnable with the structure induced on $V^n$ by $(V,E)$. Give a classification of the reducts of each $\mathcal{V}_n$, probably there are only finitely many of them. I have no idea how hard this would be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the random graph cannot interpret the random binary relation.

I’ll just answer the title question with the goal of illustrating a technique; I haven't considered $k$-ary structures. The approach is to use the property of least supports to set up a counting argument. Some equivalences are discussed at [Least supports and weak elimination of imaginaries](http://atoms.mimuw.edu.pl/?p=1281). Combined with $\omega$-categoricity we get a useful classification of all definable equivalence relations. I’ll use the following result with $M$ being the random graph.

> **Fact.** [1, Lemma 2.7(ii)] If $X\subseteq M^n$ is invariant, there is a unique smallest set $D\subset M$ such that $X$ is $D$-invariant.

“$D$-invariant” means $X$ is preserved setwise by all automorphisms that fix $D$ elementwise. “Invariant” means $D_0$-invariant for some finite $D_0.$ Since $M$ has an $\omega$-categorical theory, invariant is the same as definable, and $D$-invariant is the same as $D$-definable. The proof in [1] uses the free amalgamation property. I’m not sure whether this special case is obvious or not.

Fix:

- a finite set $M_0\subset M$
- an $M_0$-definable set $X\subseteq M^n$
- an $M_0$-definable equivalence relation ${\sim}\subseteq X\times X,$ and
- an $M_0$-definable relation $R\subseteq X\times X$ that respects ${\sim}$ i.e. it’s the preimage of a relation $R/{\sim}\subseteq (X/{\sim})\times(X/{\sim}).$

We aim to show that $(X/{\sim}, R/{\sim})$ is not isomorphic to the random binary relation.

For each complete $n$-type $p$ over $M_0$ let $X_p=\{x\in X:M\Vdash p(x)\}.$ Let $P=\{p:X_p\neq\emptyset\}.$ Pick representatives $x_p\in X_p$ for each $p\in P.$ Let $x_p/{\sim}$ denote the ${\sim}$-equivalence class of $x_p.$ By the Lemma, for each $p$ there is a unique smallest set $D$ such that $x_p/{\sim}$ is $D$-definable. We must have $D\subset \operatorname{rng}(x_p).$ Let $I_p\subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ be a minimal set of indices such that $\operatorname{rng}(x|I_p)=D$ - this step is necessary because $x_p$ might have repeated components.  Let $\hat{p}$ denote the type of $x|I_p$ over $M_0,$ implicitly reindexing if necessary, or allowing types to use free variables $x_i,i\in I_p$ instead of the usual contiguous $x_1,\dots,x_{|I_p|}.$ Note that $I_p$ and $\hat p$ do not depend on the choice of $x_p\in X_p.$

By uniqueness, whenever $x,y\in X_p$ have different supports, i.e. $\operatorname{rng}(x|I_p)\neq \operatorname{rng}(y|I_p),$ then $x\not\sim y.$ So $x/{\sim}$ is coded by $x|I_p$ modulo perhaps a permutation group acting on the indices of $I_p.$

For each $p,q\in P$ define $R_{p,q}$ on vectors $\hat{x}\in X^{I_p}$ and $\hat{y}\in X^{I_q}$ by

$$R_{p,q}(\hat x,\hat y)\iff (\exists x\in X_p)(\exists y\in X_q)(x\supseteq \hat x \wedge y \supseteq \hat y \wedge R(x,y))$$

Then for $x\in X_p$ and $y\in X_q$ we have $R_{p,q}(x|I_p,y|I_q)\iff R(x,y)$ because the choice of extension doesn’t affect the equivalence classes: by definition of $I_p$ any automorphism fixing $x|I_p$ will fix $x/{\sim},$ and similarly for $y|I_q.$ The relation $R_{p,q}$ is $M_0$-definable.

Let $d=\max_{p\in P}|I_p|.$ If $d=0$ then $X/{\sim}$ is finite, which is absurd. The $d=1$ case could be handled by symmetry, but the following counting argument happens to cover this case too. So assume $d\geq 1.$

Pick $N$ large enough that $$4^{N^d}>|P|(N^d+2^{Nd})^d.$$

Pick $p$ with $|I_p|=d.$ Use the extension property to pick $dN$ distinct vertices $x_{i,j}$ where $i\in I_p$ and $1\leq j\leq N,$ satisfying $M\Vdash \hat p((x_{i,{j_i}})_{i\in I_p})$ for each $j: I_p\to \{1,\dots,N\}.$ In graph theory terms we’re blowing up each vertex $(x_p)_i$ into $N$ vertices. It doesn’t matter whether there are edges between $x_{i,j}$ and $x_{i,k}$ for the same $i.$

For each $q\in P$ I estimate that there are at most $(N^d+2^{Nd})^d$ types over $M_0$ realized by tuples of the form $((x_{i,j})_{i\in I_p,1\leq j\leq N},y)$ with $y\in X^{I_q}$ and $M\Vdash \hat{q}(y).$ This is because the type of the tuple is determined by the binary relations, and the only freedom is how the $1$-type of each $y_k$ over $M_0$ extends to a $1$-type over $M_0\cup \{x_{i,j}:i\in I_p, 1\leq j\leq N\}.$ There are at most $N^d+2^{Nd}$ such extensions: either $y_k=x_{i,j}$ for some $(i,j),$ or else there are the $2^{Nd}$ choices of whether or not each $\{x_{i,j},y_k\}$ is an edge.

Each $y\in X$ determines values $z_y(j)\in \{1,2,3,4\}$ for each $j: I_p\to \{1,\dots,N\},$ according to whether $R_{p,q}(x_{i,j_i},y)$ and $R_{q,p}(y,x_{i,j_i})$ are false/false, false/true, true/false or true/true. By the estimate in the previous paragraph, there are at most $|P|(N^d+2^{Nd})^d$ distinct functions of the form $z_y.$ So there is some $z\in 4^{N^{I_p}}$ not equal to $z_y$ for any $y.$ In terms of the original interpretation, we can pick $\xi^j\in X_p$ with $\xi^j_i=x_{i,j_i}.$ The equivalence classes $\xi^j/{\sim}$ are distinct because they have different supports. The extension property for the random binary relation requires that there exists $y\in X$ such that $R(\xi^j, y)$ and $R(y,\xi^j)$ are false/false etc according to $z(j).$ But then $z=z_y,$ contradicting the choice of $z.$

[1] *Macpherson, Dugald; Tent, Katrin*, [**Simplicity of some automorphism groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2011.05.021), J. Algebra 342, No. 1, 40-52 (2011). [ZBL1244.20002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1244.20002).

Comment: Cool! I talked to Alex Kruckman a bit about this, he knows much more about these kind of structures then I do. He thinks, and I agree, that there should be a general result along the following lines: If $T$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical with trivial algebraic closure and weak elimination of imaginaries, and $T^*$ is another theory such that the max number of 1-types over a cardinality n set in $T^*$ grows much faster than in $T$, then $T$ does not interpret $T^*$. i believe that such a result would yield a number of new non-interpretability results between finitely homogeneous structures.

Comment: The first part of your argument, the description of definable equivalence relations in the random graph, follows from Prop 5.5.3 in Alex's thesis, which you can find here https://akruckman.faculty.wesleyan.edu/files/2019/07/thesis.pdf. His result also covers the random $k$-ary hypergraph, which could be useful for the more general question in my initial post.

Comment: So I am curious to know how far this approach can be pushed. There are a number of known bounds on types in finitely homogeneous structures, so it would be nice to have a way of getting non-interpretability results from type bounds. Of course I have to add the caveat that I am far from an expert on this kind of thing and it's possible that some of this is already known.